# Chartjs: how to render a custom component instead of the basic tooltip in React?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I have a basic doughnut chart in a React app. I want to display a custom component instead of the native tooltip. Chartjs provides a starting code (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#external-custom-tooltips), but it doesn't work and make typescript go mad.

How to add my custom component?

Comment: What did you already try? Can you provide some code (best way would be on stackblitz or codesandbox).

Comment: Hi Clafou, I have basically copy/pasted ChartJs' demo code to enable a custom tooltip. Apart from that, I have simply wrote the usual tooltip:{callback:{label: blabla}}

Comment: This may answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44556153/2358409

Comment: Yes, it is Chartjs's documentation example. But it doesn't work for me. Typescript goes mad, and once I've fixed all the type errors, no tooltip appears, even with a basic test such as displaying a "hello world" title.

Comment: @DoneDeal0 How did you solve this?